# Проблема с загрузкой товаров facebook pixel

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

имеется проблема по автозагрузке товаров в facebook, необходимые микроданные подгружены через open graph теги, но в личном кабинете отображается ошибка (см. скрин) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пишет что требуется внести сайт в список доверенных, но домен уже вписан в этот список
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, помогите решить